# How to implement server side pagination in Angular Mat-table

Tags: angular, mat-table

**Current Implementation:**
I am pre-loading all the data in a single api call then loading into the mat-table.This is what i have implemented so far. Oninit of the component i am calling an api and loading all the data into the table.

**Desired Implementation:**
When the table data has 1000s of rows, I want to call an api to load data for each page of the mat-table.

```
        <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

          <ng-container *ngFor="let item of headerRow; let i = index" matColumnDef={{headerRow[i]}}>
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{headerRow[i]}} </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">

              <mat-form-field floatLabel="never">
                <input matInput placeholder="Name" [value]="row[i]" [(ngModel)]="row[i]">

              </mat-form-field>
            </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>
          <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="headerRow"></mat-header-row>
          <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: headerRow;">
          </mat-row>
        </mat-table>
        <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
```

Comment: There are two way to provide pagination - At client side or using Server, which one do you want? Have you tried to search or implement anything?

Comment: I want to send request to the server, each time the next page is clicked.

Comment: Then which backend tech you are using? It php? C#? or?

Answer (score 1):

Basically if You want server side pagination You have to introduce some changes to You API and pass the desired parameters into it. Then make mat-table's data to be refreshed each time user is doing something that cause change as You will be keeping only 1 fixed set of rows (page). As I don't know the server's technology, allow me to just sketch a resolution for You.

1. Create an API that will return only selected items:

   - Introduce query parameters like `?page=n&size=m` and modify Your API to read those parameters from the query.
   - Use parameters `page` and `size` to make Your SQL to use `SKIP` (`page-1)*size`) and `TAKE` (`size`). Remember that You have to define them after sorting/filtering or anything that will change the number of rows. Search for Your language how to do that. I give the generic idea. For example in `C#` You can use LINQ to do the job very easily: [skip](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip?view=netframework-4.8), [take](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=netframework-4.8).
2. Get info from paginator about current state to call API with valid parameter`s values:

   - Use `@ViewChild()` to get a reference to Your paginator. Then inside Your code You can use `.pageIndex` and `.pageSize` (inputs of [MatPaginator](https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/api#MatPaginator)). You can use those values to build a valid query.
   - Use `page` EventEmmiter (again [MatPaginator](https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/api#MatPaginator) but outputs), subscribe to it and pipe the complete reload of the data set for the table.

Remember that for now on You are responsible for refreshing data on every sorting/filtering/page resizing/page changing.